# Mysql can't start due to 3306 busy

Tags: mysql

I recently moved my old server to EC2 and cannot run mysql in the new EC2 instance. I ran `sudo service mysql start` and get `start: Job failed to start` as return. Here is the error log

```
210525 15:04:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
210525 15:04:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
210525 15:04:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
210525 15:04:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
210525 15:04:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
210525 15:04:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
210525 15:04:41 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
210525 15:04:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
210525 15:04:42 InnoDB: 5.5.54 started; log sequence number 4021966302
210525 15:04:42 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '111.1.111.111'; port: 3306
210525 15:04:42 [Note]   - '111.1.111.111' resolves to '111.1.111.111';
210525 15:04:42 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '111.1.111.111'.
210525 15:04:42 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
210525 15:04:42 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
210525 15:04:42 [ERROR] Aborting

210525 15:04:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
210525 15:04:43  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 4021966000
210525 15:04:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I'm new to this and wasn't sure what to do. I tried to see if 3306 is been using but when I ran `sudo netstat -nlp` I didn't see 3306 on the list. I export my old VM as ova and upload it to S3 -> AMIs -> create instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the new server was created by my old server's snapshot, it copy everything including the bind address. I change the bind address to "127.0.0.1" and now mysql is running.

What I did:

1. `sudo less /var/log/mysql/error.lo`g (to find out the errors)
2. If you have the same error as what I have then check the my.cnf file's bind address. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. Change the bind address.
4. run `sudo service mysql start`

> Reference:
> https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-bind-address-ubuntu/
> https://serversforhackers.com/c/mysql-network-security

Answer (score 0):

try to use this `netstat -nlp|grep 3306` when you identify it, then use `killall <process>`

Comment: Hi, I tried the first command but nothing happen. Tried killall 3306 it said "3306: no process found".

Comment: Do you tried to restart?, and <process> its the program that are using that port, ex: mariaDB is using port 3306, in your terminal write `killall mariaDB`

Comment: I tried to do "sudo service mysql restart" and git "start: Job failed to start". The error log is in my question. The database is mysql. Thanks!

Comment: if you are using linux like Kali or Ubuntu, maybe you should use `systectl stop mysql.service`

Comment: My mysql status is already stop. "mysql stop/waiting" :(

Comment: I noticed my Server hostname (bind-address) is different than the hostname --all-ip-addresses. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with it?